# JAAS - request.isUserInRole sempre retornando false

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, glassfish, jaas

Estou implementando um JAAS com apenas 2 tipos de usuários, um tipo será Administrador e outro será Colaborador. Em vez de criar diretórios distintos para administrador e para colaborador, quero que ambos acessem a mesma página, a diferença é que o administrador terá alguns componentes como rendered="true" a mais que o colaborador.

Fiz um projeto teste e segui este [tutorial](http://www.greenkode.com/2011/09/user-authentication-and-authorization-using-jaas-and-servlet-3-0-login/) que funcionou normalmente.

Agora que o projeto começou para valer, abri um novo projeto e desta vez não estou conseguindo, já revi o código e configuração diversas vezes e não encontro o erro.

O método request.isUserInRole sempre retorna false.

Criei uma tabela Usuario, Grupo e uma de relacionamento UsuarioGrupo e também uma view que tem as colunas das outras tabelas com nome de nome_usuario, senha_usuario e nome_grupo.

No glassfish, criei um Realm com as seguintes configurações:

Contexto do JAAS: jdbcRealm
JNDI : Rap
Tabela de Usuários: vw_rap_grp_usr
Coluna de Nomes de Usuários: nome_usuario
Coluna de Senhas: senha_usuario
Tabela de Grupo: vw_rap_grp_usr
Coluna de Nomes de Grupos: nome_grupo

Meu web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Gestão de Projetos</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/inter/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Administrador</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Colaborador Area</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/inter/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Colaborador</role-name>
        <role-name>Administrador</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>GestaoDeProjetosRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/faces/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>Administrador</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>Colaborador</role-name>
  </security-role>  
  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/faces/AccessDenied.xhtml</location>
  </error-page>
  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Meu faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<!-- =========== FULL CONFIGURATION FILE ================================== -->

<faces-config version="2.0"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">   

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>falha</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>       
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>administrador</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>inter/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>colaborador</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>inter/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

E o LoginBean.java

```
@ManagedBean
public class LoginBean implements Serializable{

    private String usuario;
    private String senha;

    // getters e setters - ocultei para não ficar muito extenso 

    public LoginBean() {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
    }

    public String logar() {
        String message = "";
        String navto = "";
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

        try {            
            request.login(usuario, senha);            
            Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();            
            if (request.isUserInRole("Administrador")) {                
                message = "Username : " + principal.getName() + " You are an Administrator, you can really f**k things up now";
                navto = "administrador";
            } else if (request.isUserInRole("Colaborador")) {                
                message = "Username : " + principal.getName() + " You are only a Manager, Don't you have a Spreadsheet to be working on??";
                navto = "colaborador";
            }else {
                System.out.println("Nenhum deles...");
            }   

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message, null));
            return navto;
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "An Error Occured: Login failed", null));
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "falha";
        }
    }

    public void logout() {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, "/login.xhtml");
    }

}
```

A saída não me apresenta nenhum erro, mas sempre imprime "Nenhum deles..." conforme coloquei no SystemOutPrintln.

Outra observação é que se eu coloco um usuario ou senha inválido, ele mostra a mensagem "An Error Occured: Login failed" conforme o try catch, porém se o usuario e senha são válidos, a tela continua na tela de login mas com uma bolinha no canto esquerdo.

Answer (score 1):

Como que está sua configuração no Glassfish ? qual a stack que está retornando quando você coloca dados corretos ?
Por momento esqueça a autorização, faça apenas a autenticação do usuário verificando se o Principal retornado não é nulo. Comente as tags `<security-role>` e verifique primeiramente se o acesso ao DB está OK, faça um debug e analise o `Principal`.

Não tenho muito conhecimento de JSF mas porque você está usando o login de forma declarativa ?
Basta criar um form e chamar enviar um POST para `/j_security_check`, passando um `j_username` e um `j_password`

Forneça mais dados do erro em si que você está obtendo que talvez eu possa te ajudar melhor. Porque aparentemente não tem nada de errado com sua configuração.
Caso ache necessário de uma olhada aqui no [Github](https://github.com/josueeduardo/javaee/tree/master/JAAS) que possui alguns exemplos meus de JAAS.

Abraços

Answer (score 1):

Descobri o erro, na verdade estava fazendo o que muita gente também fez mas eu estava crente que estava fazendo certo. Eu estava confundindo o role com o group, então no security-role-mapping eu inverti o que era para ser role-name coloquei como group-name. 
Mesmo assim muito obrigado pela ajuda!